# Where is "Control Center" in Java 11?

Tags: java

We own Oracle Java Desktop Subscriptions and using Java 8 for Desktop Clients.
With Java 11 Oracle releases only JDK version, which includes a JRE.

With Java 11 the Control Center is missing. Is it right, that the CC is released only in OpenJDK?

Question: How do we get back the Control Center in Java 11 and or future versions using the licensed version of Java?
Why: With the Control Center we can set easily some security parameters.

Comment: There has never been anything called Control Center in java. You mean Mission Control? Or something else?

Comment: Or the Java Control Panel?

Comment: It doesn’t make much sense to have a control panel, where there is no standalone JRE.

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry! I meant the Java Control Panel...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the record, there never was a "Java Control Center".

- Java Flight Recorder (JFR) and Java Mission Control (JMC) are included in both Oracle Java 11 and OpenJDK Java 11
- The Java Control Panel which was part of the deployment tool chain that was dropped in Java 11; see the [release notes](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html).  It is not available for **either** Oracle Java 11 **or** OpenJDK Java 11.

So:

> Question: How do we get back the Control Center in Java 11 and or future versions using the licensed version of Java?

Assuming you are talking about the Java Control **Panel**, the answer is (AFAIK) you can't, and this won't change in future releases ... unless Oracle (or someone else) comes up with a replacement for the deployment tool chain.

> Why: With the Control Center we can set easily some security parameters.

<strike>It is most likely that the parameters can be set some other way.</strike>

**CORRECTION** - It appears that many of the security parameters that were configured using the Java Control Panel control the security of the Java browser plugin and Java Webstart.  JWS and the browser plugin no longer exist in Java 11.

You were interested in configuring `Control Panel > Security > Exception Site List`.  Allowed the user to mark certain sites as "safe" as a source for RIAs.  Since RIAs relied on either JWS or the Java browser plugin, this configuration property is moot.

(Or at least ... that is what I have deduced from reading the Java 8 deployment docs.)

Comment: Thank you for you answer, yes I meant the Java Control Panel and don't know why I wrote Center .. :/  Any idea where I can set security parameters with Java11?

Comment: Which security parameters?

Comment: Java Control Panel > Security > Exception Site List > e.g. add IP addresses

Comment: That setting is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 2):

As pe the release notes of Java 11:

The Java Plugin and Java WebStart technologies that were deprecated in JDK 9 and marked as candidates for removal in JDK 10, have now been removed. Please note that the **Java Control Panel, which was used for configuring the deployment technologies, has also been removed along with the shared system JRE (but not the server JRE) and the JRE Auto Update mechanism.** [More details](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html)

Comment: Thank you for the information! Ok, is there any option to set security parameters with JAVA11? I need to add an IP address for an old TapeLibrary webinterface.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the funtionalities in the control panel were pretty important to windows users. Installing certificates, for example, is a tedious process without it. Windows cert manager does not target the cacerts file and java doesn't automagically trust the windows cert stores (which is stupid).

Also the automatic updater being gone? Ridiculous. Does oracle actually think sysadmins are going to check their website for updates every day? Good thing MS rereleased their own openjdk. So sick and tired of Oracle's Shenanigans..

Long story short... it's gone, and not coming back, but luckily there are other options that satisfy your needs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/openjdk/download

Answer (score 0):

In MS OpenJDK 11 there is no JRE and there is no Java Control Panel neither.